# C++: Spawn a subprocess to execute simultaneously

Tags: c++

I have a function that is not the main function, A. This function simply iterates, say 1 to 1,000,000. At every X iteration, lets say 10,000, I want to run another function, but not stop the iteration. So it'd look something like this:

```
void iterate() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      i++;
      if ((i%10000) == 0) {
         // Spawn a process here
         // This process should start, then
         // the rest of the iterations should continue
         // while the process is running
      }
   }

}
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Searching for "c++ spawn process" turned up nothing?

Comment: The real question is why you're using a multi-process model when this is exactly what threads can handle.

Comment: OP, do you mean "process" with its very specific posix meaning, or do you mean "run some computation"? If you mean "run some computations", you are after std::thread.

Comment: @tadman my guess is that OP is abusing language and doesn't really want a subprocess. Most likely would be better served with threads. Then again, people underestimate concurrency complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on POSIX compliant systems or using Cygwin on Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void func(void)
{
    printf("Fork called\n");
}

void iterate(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        if (!(i % 10000)) {
            pid = fork();
            if (!pid) {
                func();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    wait(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    iterate();
    return 0;
}
```

`fork()` will start a child process. After the fork make you check that you are a child process and execute whatever you want. The `wait()` after the for loop will pause the parent process until the all sub processes finish executing.

Additional info about `fork()` and `wait()`:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html